# How do I print just a final sum in this problem?

Tags: c#

I am a beginner, trying to solve [Project Euler problem 1](https://projecteuler.net/problem=1):
"If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.

Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.", but, you probably know this problem.
So  I get a correct answer but my program lists all sums up to a final sum. But how do I manage to just print final sum?

```
int x = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i ++)
        {
            if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x += i);
```

Comment: First - your `WriteLine` is inside the `for` loop, so it gets executed every time you execute that loop. Second - the point of that particular exercise is to be smart about it. There is a way of doing it without loops, but it takes some math. I suggest you first fix the code as it is. After you get it working with a loop, consider other (mathematical) ways of getting at the answer. Good luck, and enjoy the puzzle!

Comment: Thanks! I solved this purely with mathematics few weeks ago, but now I started learning to program so I tried to resolve this with coding approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a Console.WriteLine inside a loop, so every time the `if` is true, a print out to the console will occur. Move the Console.WriteLine so it is outside of the loop

I think you would have quite quickly discovered this problem if you had used the debugger to step through the code line by line. Do you know how to use the debugger? If not, drop a comment and I'll write some introductory lines

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print only the final result, move the `Console.WriteLine` command out of the iteration and place it after it. This way it will execute only once.

```
int x = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i ++)
{
    if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
    {
        x += i;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should keep console.WriteLine() outside of 'for' loop,
Your code should go look like this-

```
int x=0;
for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i ++){
if (i%3==0 || i%5==0){
x+=i;
}}
console.WriteLine(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

good start bro, you can just make the Console.WriteLine(x) after the for loop

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write every time you add i to x. You can just add it and then print after you ran the for loop.

```
int x = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
    {
        x += i;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(x);
```